# SCNScene returns nil, resulting in an error

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

When `SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn")` is called, an error occurs when returning nil. The same is true if you put the `ship.scn` file provided by Apple as a sample as a `(named:)` parameter. I just don't know what's wrong.

```
guard let diceScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn") 
else { fatalError("Unable to load scene file.") }
    
if let diceNode = diceScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Dice", 
                                            recursively: true) {
    diceNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.1)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(diceNode)
}
```

I expected the "diceCollada.scn" object to appear on the ar screen on the app screen, but an error occurred when I called `SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn")`.

Comment: can you open the scene file with the xcode editor? might be a corrupted file?

Answer (score 0):

As @ZAY said in the comment it might be corrupted if you cannot open the file with the Xcode editor. So otherwise, I recommend you to open the file with REALITY COMPOSER (Which is in the developer app of the Xcode).
There is the possibility of a file direction problem. So check the direction of the file. Ensure the file and direction folder are checked as your bundle's target.

Comment: Mostafa, Reality Composer doesn't read SceneKit's `.scn` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `.scn` and `.png` files from the `art.scnassets` folder to the root directory of Xcode's Navigation pane. If this doesn't help, then your SceneKit's scene may be damaged or corrupted, or the file's name is misspelled.

[image]

---

```
guard let diceScene = SCNScene(named: "diceCollada.scn")
else { fatalError("Unable to load scene file.") }
```

---

Also make sure you checked the `Add to targets` box when you loaded the file into the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spent so much time trying to solve this, moving the files won't help. It's a weird bug. But solution is actually really simple, just click on "art" folder and uncheck the "Prefer compressed textures".
[see the solution picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2uZq.png)

You can check it again, after running the app once, and it will work perfectly.